# Flutter Provider package unable to notify listeners

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

```
class _LoadAssetState extends State<LoadAsset> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    load().then((val) => setState(() {
          Books().addBook(val);
          print('added');
        }));
    super.initState();
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var booksData = Provider.of<Books>(context);
    var books = booksData.items;
    print(books.length);
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: books.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: books[i],
        child: BookItem(),
      ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
    );
  }
  Future<Book> load() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    var targetFile = await rootBundle.load('assets/eBooks/Power.epub');
    Uint8List audioUint8List = targetFile.buffer
        .asUint8List(targetFile.offsetInBytes, targetFile.lengthInBytes);
    List<int> bytes = audioUint8List.cast<int>();
    EpubBook epubBook = await EpubReader.readBook(bytes);

    String title = epubBook.Title;
    String author = epubBook.Author;
    List<String> authors = epubBook.AuthorList;
    img.Image cover = epubBook.CoverImage;
    print(authors);

    io.Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    img.Image thumbnail = img.copyResize(cover, width: 120, height: 180);
    io.File('${tempDir.path}/Power.jpg')
        .writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(thumbnail));
    print('loaded');
    return Book(id: DateTime.now().toString(), title: title, authors: authors);
  }
}
```

**books.length returns 0 even after adding the obj using addBook method in Books(). Notify listeners is in addBook method. Book is loaded and added as print statement dictate**
*I'm not sure that i'm using Provider package correctly*

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the

```
Provider(create: (context) => Books())
```

above the widgets where you use the Provider.of(context)
(Typically above the MaterialApp)

```
Provider(create: (context) => Books(),
      child: MaterialApp(
```

Add a getter to your Books class:

```
  class Books with ChangeNotifier { 
   List<Book> _items = [];

   List<Book> get items => _items; 

  void addBook (Book obj) { 
  _items.add(obj); 
  notifyListeners();
  } 
}
```

Use the Consumer from Bloc Package:

```
Consumer.of<Books>(
builder: (context, books, child) {
return GridView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  itemCount: books.items.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => BookItem(books.items[i]),
```

Comment: I have provided the above statement in main.dart(Books provider registered) -> homescreen.dart ->loadasset.dart(listener)

Comment: no need to to use ChangeNotifierProvider in the itemsBuilder just use pass the books[i] to your BookItem()

Comment: books.length is 0 which means listeners are not hearing. Output is :   0  \n  [Robert Greene]  \n  loaded   \n added    \n   0

Comment: import './book.dart';

class Books with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Book> _items = [];                                              void addBook (Book obj) {                                        _items.add(obj);                                                        notifyListeners();                                                        } }

Comment: Updated answer.  Now you can call booksData.items and pass it into the BookItem();

Comment: Not working dude. books.length is 0 when the widget builds